# Google Webmaster Tools - Stuck during "change address" - Step 3

Tags: google-search-console

I moved my website from one domain to another in the last days and now I want to submit these changes to the Google Webmaster Tools.

**What does Step 3?**

> Check that verification methods are still present 
>   This step ensures your new and old sites are properly verified before the > move, and will remain so afterwards.

The odd thing is that I don't get any error message. The little loading icon just doesn't stop.

**My setup:**

- I have 4 different accounts in my Webmaster Tools this means 2x www and 2x non-www for each domain (old & new)
- Preferred version is set up on both accounts to www
- The rest is also identical like geographical settings or crawl delay (default)
- Both sites are verified via TXT record, I double checked it via MXToolBox
- Step 2, the 301 redirect test passes, everything okay along this line
- No https involved
- The redirect is handled via Clourflare (Page Rules)

So everything is set up correctly, the redirect works, the verification works etc. but I still can't pass Step 3. Any thoughts or questions about this? Highly appreciate your response!

Comment: If you have not set-up the new domain name as a property in Google Search Console, then you need to. When that is done, go through and verify it using verification code they provide. Then I believe your step 3 will work. Personally, I have not moved a domain via Search Console, so I cannot tell you from experience. I am just guessing based on what I believe is being said. Try it. Then let us know. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did this already what you are suggesting and I wrote it in my initial post :(

Comment: Delete your session cookies, or try a different browser.

Comment: I tried that too, no luck.

Comment: Might better in Google webmaster forums, if you haven't posted already. Some threads never get a helpful reply, but when I had issues verifying many sub domains in Search console, I get an offical reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Chrome that has not been addressed after 2-3 years of being reported by users.

The workaround is simply to visit Google Webmaster Tools from another browser, such as Safari, and the change of address will go through immediately.